# Android studio - How to set text position on center when using drawableLeft property on a Button?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to set text set on center position when using DrawableLeft on a button?

```
<Button
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_round_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_google"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:text="start with google"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="11dp"/>
```

[image]

the text `START WITH GOOGLE` is not placed on the center.
How to center it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hacky solution is to make a transparent png file or the same color as the background with the exact dimensions of `icon_google` and set it as drawableRight like so:

```
<Button
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_round_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_google"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/transparent_icon_google"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:text="start with google"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="11dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this with just a `Button`. You could wrap everything in a `ViewGroup` of some sort or you could simply adjust the paddings until you're happy with the result. I prefer the padding method.

Answer (score 1):

This move to `linierleyout`
and you have `drawebelPadinge`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).